# Visual Studio Database Project Ignoring Comments

Tags: deployment, comments, visual-studio-2019, database-project, dacpac

I am working with Visual Studio 2019. And I am using VS 2019 Database project for generating the "Dacpac" file for db deployment.

My problem is that when I am deploying the .dacpac file after making changes in any object it's deploying/updating the database. But when I am deploying the .dacpac file after adding some description as a comment for any object it's not deploying or updating the database (particular object).

So is there any way by which comments can also be deploy for any database objects by .dacpac file.

FYI, I am using MS SQL 2016 as a database.